# Vertical alignment in Bootstrap grid

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a simple Bootstrap grid, with a number of columns, and I'm trying to vertical align them to the bottom. The style looks like:

```
 .vcenter {
   display: inline-block;
   vertical-align: bottom;
   float: none;
 }
```

and the html:

```
 <div class="container">
   <div class="row">
     <div class="col-lg-4 vcenter">
       <h2>Aaaaaaaaaaaaa Bbbbbbbbbbbbbbb</h2>
     </div>
     <div class="col-lg-4 vcenter">
       45.6 kg | 151.4 cm | +1.9 %
     </div>
     <div class="col-lg-4 vcenter">
       <button class="btn-primary">cmd 1</button>
       <button class="btn-default">cmd 2</button>
     </div>
   </div>     
 </div>
```

Column 2 and 3 are aligned at the bottom properly, but column 1 not:

[image]

Demonstrated here: http://www.bootply.com/EAOSqvSYkk.

Any idea why column 1 is not aligned to the bottom?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `h2` has per default a `margin-bottom: 10px;` (at least in my Google Chrome). You either have to set this manually to `0px`:

```
h2 {
    margin-bottom: 0;
}
```

or do it for everything:

```
.vcenter * {
    margin-bottom: 0;
}
```

I would prefer to use another tag instead of `<h2>`, e.g. a `<span>`, this way wou wouldn't have to overwrite the browser-stylesheet.